Query app from excel or PowerBi with Organizational account login
I have a flask web app, and an app registration on my azure account (the tenant is "common"). One endpoint of my web app returns data that can be read by excel. In the app response i configured the header to look like this:
@app.after_request
def after(response: Response):
    response.headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = "Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"
    return response

returning 401 when the Bearer token is empty, following these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connector-authentication
but when I try to sign in from excel I get this error:

in the same link i just posted it says something about application ID URI:

For example, if accessing https://api.myservice.com/path/to/data/api,
Power Query would expect your Application ID URL value to be equal to
https://api.myservice.com.

but i don't know how to achieve what it says.
I showed this example with my personal app (localhost in azure tenant=common) but i have the same problem with my organization tenant ID
Many thanks

Could you confirm whether exposed any API scopes in your app registration as mentioned in this MS Doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/configure-microsoft-entra-for-connector?

I have one endpoint of my web app returns below sample data on running it in browser:

When I tried to access this data from Excel, I too got same error as below:

To resolve the error, make sure to add Application ID URI in registered application and create new scope by exposing an API like this:

Under Authorized client applications, you must add "Power Query for Excel" client ID: a672d62c-fc7b-4e81-a576-e60dc46e951d:

When I tried to login again in Excel after above changes, I got the data successfully like this:

For multi-tenant applications, you must provide custom URI as Application ID URI which should be one of the verified domains of your tenant.
Reference:
Connecting Excel to OAuth API on Azure - Stack Overflow by gwruck

yes but is it setup if the URI is the localhhost? if i try to add localhost, Azure throws an error.
And how is it setup if the same service principal is serving more than one URI?

Do you mean setting up Application ID URI with localhost? If yes, then it's not possible as URI must use a verified domain of the organization.

Well, I don't know if have to setup my application ID URI as localhost, i just have an app running on localhost  with Microsoft Authentication and i want excel/powerBI to connect to it. That's my goal.
